# I can't find clear explanations for all CPU processing modes of Node Exporter CPU metrics

Tags: prometheus, cpu-usage, prometheus-node-exporter

When we use *node_cpu_seconds_total* metric of Node Exporter, as seen on attached first image, Prometheus returns us total CPU usage seconds for all 8 process modes as we know.

[Node Exporter CPU modes coming with node_cpu_seconds_total metric](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uo5Ru.png)

I made lots of search to understand what those modes stand for and I almost found all of them in an article, but "nice" mode. Does anyone know what this "nice" mode stands for?

[Node Exporter CPU modes explanations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Apjo.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nice: The user code can be executed in “normal” priority, or various degrees of “below normal” priority. You can, for example, run some kind of report generation process at a lower priority and interactive processes at normal priority. Nice is when the CPU is executing a user task having below-normal priority.
from this [article](https://www.opsdash.com/blog/cpu-usage-linux.html)

Comment: The article you've shared is pretty informative for my question. Thank you.